# Creating a custom OAuth2 Grant Type

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I am building an app for a phone. The authorization process needs to be in the following way. When a user is not logged in, he will be asked to enter a phone number (like in WatsApp, Viber etc), and after he enters the phone number, an SMS will be sent to the user with an 8 digit confirmation code. When the user enters the code, an OAuth2 access token and refresh token, gets created for him and the 8 digit confirmation code gets deleted from the database. If a user logs out, he needs to do the same process again.

I want to use password authorization method since I am the resource owner. However, since I don't have a password during the authentication process, I don't really know with which parameters to create a token for him. Is it a good practice to create a new oauth2 grant type - call it "confirmation_code" and its parameters would be client_id, client_secret, username, and confirmation_code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the OAuth 2.0 "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" as per the specification on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749. Your user id is the phone number, the password is the 8 digit confirmation code you sent them.

The call to register the phone number, which will cause the SMS to be sent, obviously should not be authenticated.

Alternatively, use a normal "Authorization Code Grant". On the logon page, take the user through the steps required. First ask for the phone number and send the SMS. Then ask for the confirmation code. This may have some security advantages. The main difference with the method above is that (part of) the UI is served as HTML by the authorization server, whereas with the password credentials grant, all UI is served by the application (OAuth client).

Note that on the page served by the authorization server, you can enable multiple authentication methods. For example, you may offer the ability to enter a normal password, and only send an SMS if no password was entered. As this is a normal web application, you are basically free to do whatever is possible in a web app. The authorization grant only completes when the authorization server redirects back to the client application.

Comment: I should have mentioned the problem with doing that (I have thought of that). There is one little problem with that. I also have a web interface that accepts passwords. Since the majority of the operation happens through the phone all the usernames are phone numbers, however some can lack a password and if the user opens a web interface to use it, another sms will be send for "password reset" to the phone number and once the user inputs the code, he will be able to create a new password and login through the web interface.

Comment: @Gasim Maybe I missed something, but I don't see how that is a problem. Can you explain?

Comment: I mean because one can have a separate password that he can use in a web interface, however when using a phone... so the confirmation code and password authorization will overlap. Is it actually ok to create a custom authorization method? Security wise its the same because it uses everything the same way except for reading the code vs reading the password - different tables. My question is about generally going with the standards... Do standards allow custom grant types?

Comment: A standard is a standard, not a law. Nobody will put you in jail for deviating from it. That being said, people might hate your for it. Also, there is a reason why the standard is what it is. When you deviate, make sure it is secure.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your problem is that someone might call the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant token endpoint with either a password, either an 8 digit confirmation code. Why don't you check for both, issuing a token if either is correct?

Comment: hmm... i'll need to think about that. Thank you for the help :D